# HTTPS and HSTS headers issue AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, dns, http-headers, amazon-route53

In my scenario we currently have www3.qwerty.com routing through a few different paths. Could you please advise how we should correct this to be a better approach, possibly just redirecting even?

"The HTTP site redirects users to a new URL in a way that cannot be secured with HTTPS and HSTS headers. This leaves users open to man-in-the-middle attackers who can redirect them to a fraudulent/ spoofed version of the intended site.

“Site Does Not Enforce HTTPS” issue type for more information regarding man-in-the-middle scenarios."

```
 From "
    
    http://www3.qwerty.com/, 301, https://www.qwerty.com/
    "
```

we don't need that domain though so it'd best to just have it go directly to [www.qwerty.com](http://www.qwerty.com) rather than the reroutes either cname or load balancer came to mind.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Route53 is a DNS service. You can't do redirects with DNS. Redirects are an HTTP concept. Having said that, what is your actual issue here? What specific problem are you encountering? Are you just unhappy with the number of DNS records you have?

Comment: @MarkB ,I don't need that domain though http://www3.qwerty.com/, so it'd best to just have it go directly to www.qwerty.com rather than the reroutes either cname or load balancer came to mind.